# join() запуск потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность, join

если убрать join() программа  и потоки перестают работать. Как можно исправить?

```
public class LoaderBean {


            protected void download(List<File> files, String path, String nThreads) throws InterruptedException {

                int countTreads = 0;
                int n = Integer.parseInt(nThreads);
                int nLastThreadsNumber = files.size() % n; 
                Thread[] threads;                        

                while(countTreads < files.size()) {
                    if(countTreads + nLastThreadsNumber == files.size()) {
            threads = new Thread[nLastThreadsNumber];
        }
        else {
            threads = new Thread[n];
        }
```

Эта штука выше для того, если количество потоков не кратно длине файла - 27%5 = 2, тогда на последнем этапе создастся массив поток размера 2, а не 5, как было до этого. Каким-то непонятным образом, если на входе написать например потоков штук 100, а файл размера 25, то всё норм скачивается. Может кто объяснить почему не кидает nullpointer?

```
                    for (int j = 0; j < n && j + countTreads != files.size(); ++j) {
                        threads[j] = new Thread(new MyThread(files.get(countTreads + j), path),
                                String.format("Thread %d", j));
                    }

                    if(countTreads + threads.length <= files.size()) {
                        countTreads = countTreads + threads.length;
                    }
                    startThreads(threads);
                }
            }

            private static void startThreads(Thread[] threads) throws InterruptedException {
                for (Thread thread : threads) {
                    if(thread == null){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    thread.start();
                    //thread.join();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: судя по выложенному вами коду, ничего и не должно происходить, потоки выполняют свою работу и завершаются. Попробуйте более точно описать проблему и выложить весь, необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы, код

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в коде одна - зачем тебе делать это:

```
if(thread == null) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Просто иди дальше по массиву, используя continue.
join тут совсем тебе не надо, иначе зачем тебе каждый раз ждать, пока поток закончит свою работу, вся многопоточность потеряется.
Других проблем в данном куске кода не видно.

Comment: попробовал, ничего не происходит. Единственное, что меня @polk1lo удивляет: всегда правильно считывает, когда указано 3 потока. Однако если указать любое другое значение без join - ничего не грузит. Поправочка... кидает nulpointer, но код работает...

Comment: теперь проблема, чтобы nullpointer не вылазил)

Comment: нашёл решение, если кому-то интересно: проблема нул поинтера была, что у меня всегда постоянное количество потоков создавалось. Т.е. на входе приходит число 5, а размер файла 27. Следовательно 27%5 = 2 потока нужно на последнем шаге, а создавался массив на 5. Вот и поинтер вылазил. Код исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Строкой кода `thread.start()` Вы запускаете новый поток.
Строкой кода `thread.join()`  Вы даете указание главному потоку (который начинается со стартом `public static void main(String[] args)`) ждать завершения потока `thread`.

---

Следовательно, если вы уберете строку `thread.join()`, то главный поток не будет ждать завершения и, если он больше ничего не делает, завершает свою работу, а вместе с ним и приложение (Ваши потоки могут просто не успеть выполнить какую-то задачу).

Comment: т.е. без sleep() никак? Однако если на входе три потока, то всё успевает загрузиться, если больше - всё.

Comment: `sleep()` может помочь, но это не надежно. Когда дело доходит до потоков мало что будет гарантировано выполнятся. Дело в том, что в JVM есть такое понятие как планировщик потоков. Он отвечае за то: какой поток будет запущем первым, сколько он проработает и т.д. Так что то что 3 потока один раз успели выполниться не говорит что так будет всегда (на 5 раз может выполниться только 2 или 4)!!!

Comment: как можно изменить код, чтобы всё более толково работало?

Comment: Чем Вам не нравится `join`?

Comment: как бы не совсем параллельно выполняется, а как-то всё последовательно

Comment: Значит Вы плохо спроектировали Вашу задачу. Делать отдельный метод, который будет запускать потоки точно не нужно. Для этого есть `Thread.start()`. Вижу Вы работаете со списком файлов, ну так вот передайте каждому потоку по файлу и запустите их и будет Вам паралельность :)

Comment: просто количество поток разнится, на входе параметром задается, и я не понимаю, как сразу весь массив запустить

Comment: с завершением main обрываются только потоки демоны. Обычные потоки отрабатывают до конца и только потом программа завершает свою работу.